# A Puzzle That Is Stated Monumentally

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, poetry

> Hasting, now we near our end
>   "Wagon" hints at where we tend.
>   Nothing was too hard: we're free!
>   Ah, Sting! Now where's your victory?
>   Hating snow yet undismayed
>   Shown giants, we were unafraid.
>   As night now falls we huddle near.
>   Wanton sigh meets stifled tear.

Contemplation of this verse should lead you to the answer, which is a noun. In a famous instance, the answer is preceded by identical alternatives.

Comment: *A hard, howling, tossing water scene / Strong tide was washing hero clean /*...

Comment: @f'' Nice. I have never seen that one. That'll learn me not to be American.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each line begins with an anagram of

> Washington

so I guess that's the answer. The title refers to

> Washington State and the Washington Monument.

The comment about "preceded by identical alternatives", refers to

> Surely the most famous of the Washington clan, George Washington. His first name can be read as "ge or ge", hence identical alternatives.

(I should remark that f'' clearly got this before I did, but that I solved it before noticing his comment.)

[Note: some of the details here were added by the original questioner; thanks, Hugh!]

Comment: Most of the way there. I'll put in a few details, if that's ok.